# What is the <@ operator in PostgreSQL 8.4?

Tags: postgresql, operators

I am having trouble decyphering what this operator is doing. I know that it is somehow comparing the array's, but I can find no documentation on it.  I also have tried >@ but that seems to error.  Google yealded bad results ad when I search for "at operator" it isn't very specific. Any information would be much appreciated.

I also have not (at least I don't think so) defined any new operators in the database.

```
SELECT id 
FROM organizations
WHERE  ARRAY[56] <@ ancestry
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html):

```
<@  is contained by
```

When your array `ancestry` has the value `56`, the result will be `true`.